# Where I have to move a file in order to have it not be accessible via my webserver?

Tags: php

I have a connection php file with my database password on it. It resides in includes directory for my paypal store on my site. Trying to work out where I can move that folder and file so no-one can see it?

```
<?php
include('var/includes/connection.php');
```

or

```
 include('../../../includes/connection.php');
```

My file is in /var/www/html/foo/foo/includes/connection.php

Comment: The question is not fully clear. And it is not even so much in topic, i guess that the php tag here is for configuration issues not related to a specific script (ask [superuser](http://superuser.com/) next time). However judging what you wrote above I came to 2 conclusions. Maybe you wanted to use the main linux `/var` folder, in this case are you sure your php is not constrained inside some specific directory? Or.. you wanted just to go a pair of stap above so you should have used `../var` because calling `/var` call the very top var folder of the linux distros..

Comment: Hope my edit is makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you calling for root is the root of the files served by your http server, generally is used as standard `/var/www`, however this can change based on your configuration.

Is the very first directory accessible by requests done to your server, so you have: http://www.yoursite.com and it will be referenced to `/var/www`

If you move a file in a directory that is not inside that path will not be accessible, but this doesn't mean that you have to recurse the /var path, you could also put your file inside `/home/myusername/connection.php` just as example.

With a normal configured webserver there's no chance that a remote attacker could obtain the variables stored inside that file because the php file is processed, however let's say that because a misconfigured http server config the php are not executed it will be served as plain text revealing your data.

Hence why is suggested to move the file outside the browsable range of folders and access it by including it from php like

```
<?php
include('/home/user/myconfig/connection.php');
```

I would pick a more organized location tho.

Comment: Still I wonder why when I did move it to var directory it rendered the php null and void.

Comment: the question is a bit confusing... Note that if a daemon/process is constrained/sees root as some defined directory, no amount of ".." will make it go back on the *real* filesystem in certain directives. I would also use more standard directories, namely /usr/local/etc for local configuration files.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro depends from the configuration of your php.ini and the access level of the user that runs the webserver recalling the php engine or the php process manager in the case for example of php5-fpm service. The limit itself of php you are referring to is called as php **open_basedir**, if this directive is unconfigured, or is permissive the only limit will be the read capability of the user running the php or the webserver/php process (for apache is often user www-data). In this case is possible to place a config everywhere. I'm for a standardized path too for being more organized tho.

Comment: Someone should request topic to be re-opened as many people have trouble with this and I've been confused about it for a long time but too scared to ask for ridicule.

Comment: @cea you could start to edit the title first like, where i have to move a file in order to have it not be accessible via my webserver?